# How to determine when last integer has been entered? Java

Tags: java, loops, arraylist, integer

I currently have to enter a letter to stop the while loop and print out the number list. 
Is there a better way to determine when the last int has been entered?

```
` Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter a sequence of integer values" +
                    " to be sent to the server");
            List<Integer> numberList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            while(scanner.hasNextInt()) {
                numberList.add(scanner.nextInt());
            }
            System.out.println(numberList);
            os.write(String.valueOf(numberList));
            scanner.close();`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it as follows:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Program {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a sequence of integer values to be sent to the server (x to terminate)");
        List<Integer> numberList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        String[] data = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");
        int i = 0;
        while (i < data.length && data[i].matches("\\d+")) {// The regex \d+ matches only integers
            numberList.add(Integer.parseInt(data[i]));
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println(numberList);
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter a sequence of integer values to be sent to the server (x to terminate)
10 20 30 X
[10, 20, 30]
```

Also, do not close `Scanner` for `System.in` as it also closes `System.in` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a sequence of integer values to be sent to the server");
final List<Integer> numberList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
int scanned;
do {
    final int scanned = scanner.nextInt();
    numberList.add(scanned);
} while (scanner.hasNextInt() && scanned != yourChar);
os.write(String.valueOf(numberList));
scanner.close();`
```

I hope I understood your problem correctly.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid the input of the character but instead trying to implement functionality which knows - I hope this clarifies.

Comment: Ok my bad, Arvind's answer is perfect, there is nothing to add !